# Truly classical limit of classical ideal gas

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, ideal-gas, partition-function

It's well-known that a classical statistical mechanical treatment of an ideal gas leads to a fundamental equation which is not extensive. For $N$ particles, one arrives at a per-particle partition function $z = V[2\pi mk_BT^{3/2}]/h^3$ and thus, naively, a partition function for the overall system of
$$Z = z^N$$
which, on using $F = -k_BT \ln Z$, leads us to
$$F = -Nk_BT\ln z = -Nk_BT\ln (V[2\pi mk_BT^{3/2}]/h^3)$$
which, because of the $V$ dependence in the logarithm, is "more than extensive". This is the so-called Gibbs paradox, and its well-known high-temperature solution is division of the naive partition function by a permutation factor $N!$.

My question is about a limit in which this naive partition function should be "correct". In particular, suppose now that each of the particles in the ideal gas are in their own volumes $V_i$, $V_i = V_j$ for all $i,j$. Since they are now truly distinguishable, we should be able to argue that $Z$ as computed above is the correct partition function for this system. However, I'm struggling to see how the partition function is extensive in this case.

To analyze, let's imagine we index each subsystem with $i$. We have $F(T,V,N)$ ($V = \sum_i V_i$, with $V_i = V_j$ for all $i,j$) as our fundamental equation and want to show that $\lambda F(T,V,N) = F(T,\lambda V, \lambda N)$. One way to imagine effecting this scaling is that each $V_i \to \lambda V_i$, and the number of subsystems obeys $N \to \lambda N$, where each of these "new" subsystems is getting their own new volumes etc.
Then we should have
$$F(T,\lambda V, \lambda N) = \sum_{i = 1}^{\lambda N}(-k_BT\ln z_i) = -k_BT \sum_{i = 1}^{\lambda N}\ln (\lambda V_i[2\pi mk_BT^{3/2}]/h^3) = -\lambda Nk_BT\ln (\lambda V_i[2\pi mk_BT^{3/2}]/h^3),$$
but again this is not extensive because of the logarithm. If it were extensive, we would expect a final result of
$$\lambda F(T,V,N) = -\lambda Nk_BT\ln (V_i[2\pi mk_BT^{3/2}]/h^3).$$
How does one proceed here?

Comment: Why do you say your final formula is not extensive? $V_i$ do not increase; their number, $N$, increases. Maybe there is something I do not understand.

Comment: However your perfect gas with particles in cells of volume $V_i$ does not correspond to an ideal gas in a volume $V=\sum_i V_i$.

Comment: Please see my edit for why I say it's not extensive. Perhaps I have erred though. @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90

Comment: Your argument is not easy to follow: what's the meaning of summing over values of an index going up to real values? ($\lambda N$)

Comment: When you multiply the system in the sense of the Euler homogeneous function theorem, you go from $V$ to $\lambda V$ and from $N$ to $\lambda N$; after this multiplication, volume per particle remains $V_i$. So you can't scale $V_i$ to $\lambda V_i$, that is a foreign operation here. Multiplication of the system has to preserve intensive properties, thus density, thus volume per particle.

Comment: Ah I see, @JánLalinský. So you are saying that I should remove the $\lambda V_i$ because the increase in volume is already accounted for in my sending $N \to \lambda N$ (since we are adding that many more systems with volume $V_i$ (\sum_{i = 1}^{\lambda N} V_i = N\lambda V_i = \lambda V)?

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 This is true, but it's true about many of these extensive arguments in classical thermodynamics. We always are scaling strictly discrete systems by a real number.

Comment: @EE18 yes, if you want to get multiplied system, you must not change $V_i$ in this reasoning. If you changed it into $\lambda V_i$, then you would get total changed volume $\lambda^2 N V_i = \lambda^2 V$, which is not $\lambda V$.

Comment: I see. Thank you! Happy to checkmark an answer to this effect if you’d like @JánLalinský

Comment: OK I've put that into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you multiply the system in the sense of the Euler homogeneous function theorem, you go from $V$ to $\lambda V$ and from $N$ to $\lambda N$; after this multiplication, volume per particle remains $V_i$. So you can't scale $V_i$ to $\lambda V_i$, that is a foreign operation here. Multiplication of the system has to preserve intensive properties, thus density, thus volume per particle.

So if you want to get multiplied system, you must not change $V_i$. If you changed it into $\lambda V_i$, then you would get total changed volume $\lambda N\lambda V_i =\lambda^2 NV_i=\lambda^2 V$, which is not equal to $\lambda V$.

Comment: $V_i$ here is not a volume per particle and the final result should not be extensive. For $V_i$ to be intensive it would have to be the total volume divided by $N$. The fact that with distinguishable particles you don't get an extensive system is the point of the Gibbs paradox and you cannot and should not try to work around it

Comment: @SmallPieceOfBread please read the original question, for all $i$, particle $i$ is assumed to be in its own distinguishable $V_i = V/N$.

Comment: He's assuming a different set of constraints than just one volume $V$, and this implies different multiplicity and different Boltzmann entropy and different partition function.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add a more general answer to the specific and precise answer by @JánLalinský.

The starting paragraph of this question reproduces a widespread opinion about classical statistical mechanics. Then, in the attempt to find a properly behaving partition function, a solution in terms of a volume $V_i$ pertaining to each molecule seems to solve the problem.

I note that from the formal point of view, such a solution is equivalent to the usual introduction of the $\frac{1}{N!}$ counting factor. Indeed, by using Stirling's approximation, one ends with a $V/N$ dependence in the logarithm, corresponding to the symmetric choice $V_i=V/N$. However, interpreting such a result as if each particle would have an available volume $V/N$ is not consistent with the starting physical picture of an ideal gas in a container of volume $V$, where each particle can be everywhere in that volume.

Instead of introducing *ad hoc* constraints, I would reconsider the reasons for the $\frac{1}{N!}$ counting factor. The problem with extensivity originates from the assumption that the number of microstates in a phase space volume ${\mathrm d}^{3N}q ~{\mathrm d}^{3N}p$ is
$$
dW = \frac{{\mathrm d}^{3N}q ~{\mathrm d}^{3N}p}{h^{3N}}.
$$
However, on the one hand, such a naive assumption would result in non-extensive thermodynamics. On the other hand, at a macroscopic level, the exact way we label each particle should be irrelevant, then the number of microstates should be reduced by the number of permutations of $N$ labels, providing a self-consistent justification of the $\frac{1}{N!}$ correction within classical statistical mechanics, with the added bonus of extensiveness.

Comment: Interesting. If labeling of particles should be irrelevant in macroscopic physics, then the number of microstates should be irrelevant in macroscopic physics as well, because the two things imply each other. So whether the multiplicity is $W$ or $W/N!$ or $W/N^N$ should be irrelevant as well. I think this is actually a deep insight; the important thing is that entropy of macroscopic system be defined so that i'ts a homogeneous function of $U,V,N$, and fixing the factor by hand by $N!$ or $N^N$ is fully justified by this ends. Ideological reasons for this fixing seem secondary.

Comment: Thank you for this very nice addition!

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to further add to the previous answers by pointing to the very nice paper ["Testing the Foundations of Classical Entropy: Colloid Experiments" by Cates & Manoharan](https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.04030). This paper deals with collections of colloids, which are mesoscopic particles that really are distinguishable on the microscopic scale. Which definition of entropy is correct for these colloids? It is possible to experimentally measure their entropy, and one finds that (to quote from the abstract) "the experimental facts point firmly to an `informatic' interpretation that dates back to Gibbs: entropy is determined by the number of microstates that we as observers choose to treat as equivalent when we identify a macrostate." The $1/N!$ term is justified because we are choosing to ignoring the microscopic differences between colloids and are not distinguishing between them.

The authors further examine similar symmetry factors that arise when considering the contribution to the free energy of symmetric molecules due to rotational degrees of freedom. Colloidal "molecules" are not quite symmetric (again, because their "colloidal atoms" are actually not identical), but similar "informatic" considerations indicate that they can be treated as symmetric -- an assumption that is validated by experiments.

Overall a highly recommended paper on the subject!